# MySQL - Insert into data or update if exists

Tags: php, mysql

INSERT only once into MySQL or update if exists. Here `ticket_id` is unique key but data not insert nor update.

```
 if(isset($_POST['A1'])){
        $seat_no = $_POST['A1'];
        $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO ticket_details (ticket_id,".$seat_no.") VALUES('".$ticket_id."','".$ticket_status."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ticket_details SET ".$seat_no." = '".$ticket_status."' WHERE ticket_id = '".$ticket_id."'";     
        mysql_query($sql_2);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['A2'])) {
        $seat_no = $_POST['A2'];
        $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO ticket_details (ticket_id,".$seat_no.") VALUES('".$ticket_id."','".$ticket_status."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ticket_details SET ".$seat_no." = '".$ticket_status."' WHERE ticket_id = '".$ticket_id."'";     
        mysql_query($sql_2);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['A3'])){
        $seat_no = $_POST['A3'];
        $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO ticket_details (ticket_id,".$seat_no.") VALUES('".$ticket_id."','".$ticket_status."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ticket_details SET ".$seat_no." = '".$ticket_status."' WHERE ticket_id = '".$ticket_id."'";     
        mysql_query($sql_2);
    }
```

**Here I have solved the above code as per [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205207/5356229) **

```
if(isset($_POST['A1'])){
        $seat_no = $_POST['A1'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ticket_details (ticket_id,".$seat_no.") VALUES('".$ticket_id."','".$ticket_status."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  ".$seat_no." = '".$ticket_status."' ";       
            $res = mysql_query($sql);

        }
        if(isset($_POST['A2'])) {
        $seat_no = $_POST['A2'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ticket_details (ticket_id,".$seat_no.") VALUES('".$ticket_id."','".$ticket_status."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  ".$seat_no." = '".$ticket_status."' ";       
            $res = mysql_query($sql);

        }
        if(isset($_POST['A3'])){
        $seat_no = $_POST['A3'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ticket_details (ticket_id,".$seat_no.") VALUES('".$ticket_id."','".$ticket_status."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  ".$seat_no." = '".$ticket_status."' ";       
            $res = mysql_query($sql);
        }
```

Comment: Define 'not working'

Comment: @Pred data not insert nor update

Comment: var_dump($_POST) and please post the oupput here

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql?rq=1 have a look..

Comment: I think you need to add this piece of code: `mysql_query('COMMIT')` or this one: `mysql_query('SET autocommit=1')`. Also, are you sure that each `isset` is returning a `True` value?

Comment: @omar I have added Answer in my question section. Actually it does not need key to update the row So, I removed `WHERE ticket_id = '".$ticket_id."'` and it works !!

Answer (score -1):

> Use `INSERT {...} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Read [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Also, this is a Duplicate Question: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Comment: Read the question and the queries again. Flag as dupe, do not post answer. This answer has almost no useful parts, please read [answer] in [help]